# VSTO: How to refresh a formula when a cell value changes

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

Let's say I have the formula =MyCustomFunction(D2), where MyCustomFunction is writen in an Excel AddIn using C#

How can I, in a sensible way, tell my formula to re-run when cell D2 is changed?

Answer (score 1):

If the penalty on performance is not too great i.e. the spreadsheet is not huge with many calculations, then can you not simply set `Application.Volatile=True` in your function?